# A simple factoring problem $3x^3 - x^2 -12x + 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, cubics

I'm stuck on a simple factoring problem of

$$3x^3 - x^2  -12x + 4$$

I keep coming up with

$$x^2(3x - 1) -4(3x - 1) = (3x - 1) (x^2 - 4) = 3x^3 -12x - x^2 + 4 =
3x^3 - x^2 - 12x + 4$$

but it doesn't seem to be right, can anyone point out my mistake?

Comment: maybe use mathjax

Comment: You _have_ done the correct decomposition, just not went far enough.

Comment: You still have "something" to decompose, but what you've done so far is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $x^2(3x - 1) -4(3x - 1)$, factor out $(3x-1)$ to get $(x^2-4)(3x-1)$.

Knowing that $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$, we get $(x-2)(x+2)(3x-1)$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

complete the decomposition using:
$$
x^2-4=(x-2)(x+2)
$$